# How to do chmod for a file using telnet in perl?

Tags: perl

I'm trying to do a chmod for a file using telnet in Perl. When i do the below its not working.

```
use Net::FTP;
$login='user';
$pass='user1';

$ftp = Net::FTP->new('xx.xxx.xx.xxx' ,Debug => 3) or die "Cannot connect";
$ftp->login($login, $pass) or die "Can't log $login in\n";
$ftp_cmd->write("sudo chmod 777 BuildStat*.log");
```

Can i know why it doesn't work?

Thanks,
Sharath

Comment: This is just a wild guess, but is the remote system waiting for your password on the sudo?

Comment: No, it has successfully logged in.

Comment: @Sharath Having logged in does not (usually) mean one does not have to enter a sudo password. Moreover, where is the `$ftp_cmd` variable set? What errors do you get? And (always) add `use strict; use warnings;`.

Comment: Yeah, I mean running sudo on the `chmod` will still (usually) require a password.  That's what it may be waiting for.

Answer (score 1):

[`Net::FTP`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::FTP) is intended just for transferring files.

> #### OVERVIEW
>
> FTP stands for File Transfer Protocol. It is a way of transferring files between networked machines. The protocol defines a client (whose commands are provided by this module) and a server (not implemented in this module). Communication is always initiated by the client, and the server responds with a message and a status code (and sometimes with data).
>
> The FTP protocol allows files to be sent to or fetched from the server. [read more...](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::FTP#OVERVIEW)

The [`write`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::FTP#THE-dataconn-CLASS) method that you're using has nothing to do with sending commands to the server, but is instead about transferring data.

To perform a `sudo chmod` command, you'll need to use [`Net::Telnet`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::Telnet), [`Net::SSH`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::SSH) or some other interface.

Comment: Some FTP server implementation actually support the `chmod` operation via the `SITE` command. SFTP also supports it. Though, they don't go with `sudo`.